# ¿Es posible añadir un nuevo tipo de perfil en GitLab, a los ya existentes de desarrollador y Master?

Tags: permisos, gitlab

Estoy empezando a usar GitLab y mi problema es el siguiente.

Lo que necesitaría es tener un tipo de perfil, por ejemplo desarrollador, que pudiese hacer push libremente sobre un rama.
Que ese mismo perfil de desarrollador, tenga que solicitar a un perfil superior al suyo, por ejemplo master, para mergear en otra rama, por ejemplo llamada CI.
Y que un perfil superior a master revise esos cambios para mergear definitivamente de CI en la rama master.

Con los permisos que vienen por defecto en GitLab, no soy capaz de conseguierlo.
¿Se puede añadir un nuevo tipo de perfil? o ¿hay alguna manera de solventar mi problema?

Comment: ¿Gitlab versión gratuita o la de paga?

Comment: Creo que es la versión gratuita

Answer (score 0):

No de momento, [la incidencia](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/12736) ha sido levantada hace tiempo para gitlab community, y como verás no hay planes de soportar esta nueva característica.

Cabe mencionar que en la verisón de paga hay más tipos de perfiles que en la versión community ( como el perfil de auditor ), así que te recomiendo revisar si te conviene migrar a la versión de paga.

La buena noticia es que puedes lograr lo que deseas con la versión de comunidad mediante [brazos protegidos](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html), esta característica fue agregada desde  GitLab Starter 8.11.
Para configurarlo debes de ir a `Settings ➔ Repository` y buscar la sección `Protected branches`, y una vez allí seleccionar el brazo que deseas ( CI en tu caso ).

[image: Permisos de push en brazo protegido]